# How do you port a Windows-based application written in Delphi to different platforms such as Mac, iPhone and into a web-based application?

Tags: windows, port, multiplatform

Currently, it is just a windows-based application (slowed down guitar software) written in Delphi. However, I do have plans to port them to the following platforms :

1. Mac
2. iPhone
3. Web-based

How do I go about this? What is the bes programming language to use? What kind of developers do I need to look for? And how long will these projects be?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the Delphi code, then take a look at [Lazarus/FreePascal](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/). I have to say that I don't have used it for more than a Hello World yet, so you have to evaluate yourself if it can help you, but it's free and it supports Windows/Mac/Linux. Windows Mobile is also supported.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 and 2 you'd be looking at Cocoa, for 3 you could either go Flash/Java Applet/Silverlight depending on how complex the software is. Obviously Flash would not be the best to use for large projects. But Silverlight and Java Applets are capable platforms that can suite just about any need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can not simply "port" Delphi code into all those enviroments. Ok, moving Delphi logic via Delphi.NET to web based may be simple, but using delphi code for Mac or iPhone... Harder. Probably you will have to rewrite it from scratch, most probably in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. I was already thinking along those lines. Yeah, I am thinking of dropping Delphi for the Web-based and start from scratch for the web-based because I have heard so much of the power of Java. Although my only constraint is the whole Delphi (windows) application will be put to waste, especially now that its being enhanced on some features. Aren't there some codes in Delphi that can be salvaged for Java?

Comment: I am afraid that porting Delphi to Java is simply impossible. Delphi and Java use different frameworks, so you can try to translate only bussines logic (only if you have good layer separation, ie: bussines is separated from UI code).